# how to compare a table with itself under a condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

hi i need some help i have a table sells as below ..i want to compare it with itself and display a result where company should be not equal to company and price should be equal to price..i have tried many queries in mysql but not getting desired result please help me to do that!! tell the correct query
will be very much thankful to you guys !!

```
sells(company,drink,price)
```

Query i tried

```
mysql>'select company,drink,price from sells JOIN s ON(price=price1) where (comp
any1!=company);'
```

while s is a copy table of sells

```
+----------------+----------------+-------+
| company        | drink          | price |
+----------------+----------------+-------+
| PepsiCo        | Mirinda        |    45 |
| PepsiCo        | Pepsi          |    45 |
| Coca-Cola      | Coca-cola zero |    45 |
| Nestle         | Nescafe        |    35 |
| Nestle         | Nescafe        |    35 |
| Nestle         | Nescafe        |    35 |
| Nestle         | Nescafe        |    35 |
| Nestle         | Nescafe        |    35 |
| Nestle         | Nescafe        |    35 |
| Coca-Cola      | Coca-cola zero |    45 |
| Shezan         | Twister        |    25 |
| Nestle         | Fruita vitals  |    25 |
| Murree Brewery | Big Apple      |    35 |
| Murree Brewery | Big Lemon      |    35 |
| Murree Brewery | Big Orange     |    35 |
| Murree Brewery | Peach Malt     |    35 |
| Murree Brewery | Lemon Malt     |    35 |
| Murree Brewery | Apple Malt     |    35 |
+----------------+----------------+-------+
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this?

```
SELECT T1.company, T2.company, T1.price 
FROM sells T1 
JOIN sells T2
WHERE 
T1.company != T2.company
AND
T1.price = T2.price
GROUP BY T1.company, T1.price;
```